# How can I set margin-left using media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set `margin-left` of the content section to `175px`. When I resize the window to a smaller size, the toggle-menu button and collapsing side menu appears and my static side menu disappears, so I wrote a function to set `margin-left` of the content section to '0px' when I toggle the ‘toggle-menu’ button to hide collapsing side menu, but when I resize the window back to a larger size the margin-left still remains '0px'.
I need to set back margin-left to '175px' when I resize back to the larger size.

This is my scenario, and how do I fix this bug???

Comment: Add your code, whatever you have tried so far. Otherwise this explanation will look boring and people will close your question.

Comment: Add your code kindly, so that we can give you better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `!important` to override an inline style on large screens

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  #content {
    margin-left: 175px !important;
  }
}
```

P.S.: Change value 1024px as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  /* your CSS here */
  #content {
    margin-left: 175px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code here because from your explanation could not get your point.